# Google Maps API won't work on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API custom marker on my website, it works fine in desktop browser but it won't appear in a mobile browser. There's an error in my console:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

I get the data using ajax. Here's the javascript:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-0.7893, 113.9213);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    scrollwheel: false, 
    mapTypeControl: false,
    styles: []
};

var locations = response;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved with adding fixed height to the #map (previously was 100%).

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the error you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the "locations.length" exist, if it does not it will return null and will error on the length value. You can do something like this -

```
if (!locations ==0){
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
....
```

You can find some more answers [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009629/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-null)

Comment: *Check if the "locations.length" exist* - where are you doing that in the above code?